# Fuzzy Grouping Needs Enterprise SQL Edition?

Tags: sql, ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am running an Microsoft SQL Server Business Intelligence x64 server with SSIS setup on it. I have a few packages running fine but when I include one that has a fuzzy grouping control I get the following error:

**"The Fuzzy Grouping 1 cannot run on the installed edition of Integration Services. It requires Enterprise Edition(64-bit) or higher."**

I am rather confused as I would have thought that running the Buisness Intelligence version of SQL server would allow all the SSIS toolbox components.

Can anybody shed some light on this as it is very confusing!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found this

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2012/04/18/an-important-consideration-for-ssis-and-sql-server-2012-business-intelligence-edition.aspx

Explaining basically it is just MS being jerks. How ridiculous not including all the components in the business intelligence edition. Just plain rude!

If anyone actually knows the reason for this I would love to know as it baffles me!

Comment: The cost of SSIS is included in the license for SQL Server. They give away much of the functionality for Standard Edition but Fuzzy Grouping, Fuzzy Lookup and ... one other are reserved for Enterprise Edition customers. That's a choice MS sales and marketing has made for what feature sets go into which release. If you don't like it, provide feedback via Connect.microsoft.com. Alternatively, write your own fuzzy components. Look up terms like double metaphone, ngram comparison and Levenshtein distance for some interesting approaches.